# VBA, Skip Cell If

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop through my range and incorporate the logic that if B2:B100 is "No" then skip.

Original code:

```
 Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A100")
        FilePaths.Add cell.Value
    Next cell
```

Trying:

```
If cell.Range("B2:B100") <> "Yes" Then
```

Not sure on where to go next.  I want to go to next cell in col A, or continue back into col A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `Offset` to point to a `Range` at given rows and/or columns offsets from referenced one

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("A2:A100")
    If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 <> "NO" Then FilePaths.Add cell.Value2
Next cell
```

Comment: thanks for the catch: edited. btw ... you may want to mark the answer as accepted. thank you